# Trying to make a route to delete a profile and a user from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my first post on StackOverflow :).

I have made a delete route in express to delete the user and his profile:

```
// @route   DELETE api/profile/
// @desc    Delete user and profile
// @access  Private
router.delete(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOneAndDelete({ user: req.user.id })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(req.user.id);
        User.findOne({_id: req.user.id }).then(user=>console.log(user));
        User.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.user.id });
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.json({ success: true });
      });
  }
);
```

After I make the delete request from Postman with the user's token I get the success response, but when I check MongoDB, the profile is gone, but the user is still there.

The first noob idea I got was that the problem is because of the passport, that I'm not getting the right id back. I was wrong ofc, the profile was gone, and the 2 console.log's I added were returning the right user id and user:

```
5f6a380f874e5c2fe454ac10
{
  _id: 5f6a380f874e5c2fe454ac10,
  name: 'test Testeson',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  password: '$2a$10$uiq7Q080gS/.4xEbF2W/cuXG2MgnacqObKTLezUyuHBI0qnFB1Dca',
  date: 2020-09-22T17:44:47.254Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Then I thought it was a javascript async problem, I have stared at it for a very long time, and I don't see the problem, I even tried to refactor with await async and wrapped the whole callback function in an async wrapper. Which was unnecessary.

I even checked the MongoDB user's permissions, but it was ok, ofc, the profile was deleted...
And the mongoose user schema is this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Maybe it's a small noobish, stupid mistake, but I have been stuck for hours...

So any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you, :)

Comment: Have you checked the actual database collection to see if the user is still there? You also seem to be using two collections in your code `Profile` and `User`

Comment: Of course, after the Postman delete request and the success response, I have logged into MongoDb's Atlas and checked that the profile was gone, and the user in the user collection was still there...

Comment: Is the `_id` of the user the same with the `_id` of the profile? It might be that they are different if they are created by MongoDB.

Comment: They are the same: check out the 2 console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding .then() block to findOneAndDelete() and see.

`User.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.user.id }).then();`

For me also if then block was not there operation were not successful, after adding then block only the operations were successfully executing.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your code to use async/await instead and see if it works. You're probably chaining `.then()` incorectly. I write something like this:

```
router.delete(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.user;
    try {
      await Profile.findOneAndDelete({ user: id });
      await User.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id });
      res.json({ message: "Success" });
    } catch(e) {
       res.sendStatus(500)
    }
  }
);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, it was an async problem, the last then scope was wrong.

It should have been inside and chained with : 

 User.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.user.id }).then(() => {
        res.json({ success: true });
      });